# Fit a DataFrame into a model using TFDS data

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, dataset, tensorflow-datasets

I have a dataset in a csv right now that contains data in this format:

| text | class |
| --- | --- |
| text1 | 0 |
| text2 | 1 |

I have an RNN that would like to test my dataset on to check its performance. The RNN can be found [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/text/tutorials/text_classification_rnn).

In that case, the dataset is loading a dataset from `TFDS` by using `tfds.load()`.

Which way should I use to be able to fit my `.csv` data (I guess my DataFrame) and bring it into an acceptable form to be used by the pre-defined model?

Please feel free to comment with any clarification questions if my question is not clear. Thank you very much in advance for your support.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow")! Questions that ask for general guidance regarding a problem approach are typically too broad and are not a good fit for this site. People have their own method for approaching the problem and because of this there cannot be a correct answer. Give a good read over [Where to Start](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6366/where-to-start/6367#6367), and  [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") then edit your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using the `tf.data.Dataset` API. Check out this [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/pandas_dataframe). Here is a working example based on your data structure:

```
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf

df = pd.DataFrame(data= {'text': ['some text', 'some more text'], 'class': [0, 1]})
labels = df.pop('class')
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((df, labels))

for x, y in dataset:
  print(x, y)
```

```
tf.Tensor([b'some text'], shape=(1,), dtype=string) tf.Tensor(0, shape=(), dtype=int64)
tf.Tensor([b'some more text'], shape=(1,), dtype=string) tf.Tensor(1, shape=(), dtype=int64)
```